# Interpolating vertex colors with trilinear coordinates instead of barycentric

Tags: graphics, color, geometry, textures

In 3D graphics, vertex attributes like vertex normals, texture coordinates, and vertex colors are interpolated over the surface of triangles using *barycentric* coordinates. In actual fact it's more complex than this and there's a rabbit hole of perspective correct adjustment and all sorts, but indulge me for a moment. Here's what this looks like for vertex colors, and *Mathematica* handles everything about the interpolation behind the scenes:

```
vtxs = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}};
cols = {Red, Green, Blue};
tri = Polygon[vtxs, VertexColors -> cols];
pt = {1, 1/2}/2;
Graphics[{tri,
  {Yellow, PointSize[Large], Point[pt], Line[{pt, #}] & /@ vtxs},
  MapThread[
   Text[Style[#1, FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 24], #2] &, 
    {{"R", "G", "B"}, vtxs}],
  Style[{Text["u", {.3, .1}], Text["v", {.2, .65}], 
    Text["1-u-v", {.7, .1}], 
    Text[TraditionalForm[p], pt + {1, 1}*0.04]}, White, FontSize -> 24]
  }]
```

[image: barycentric vertex colors]

The color at $p$ is a weighted combination $p_c=Rw + Gv + Bu$ where $(u,v,w=1-u-v)$ are the relative areas of the subtriangles such that $u+v+w=1$.

I want to find a reasonably efficient way to interpolate the colors for any triangle *without* using barycentric coordinates, but using *trilinear coordinates* instead, and see what images this creates.

That is, we drop a perpendicular to the nearest edge and get a point on that edge, possibly indexing into the $RG,GB,RB$ gradients along the edges, and then weighting the combination of these colors by the trilinear distances or areas of the three regions - whatever is more appropriate as it's all experimental. Any other suggestions for how to interpolate vertex colors using trilinears is welcome.

[image: trilinear interpolation]

This is my code so far.
The next step is to interpolate the corner colors over a pixel grid and make an image, instead of a `Graphics` with a single point:

```
SeedRandom[123456789];
poly = RandomPolygon[3];
shell = RegionUnion[MeshPrimitives[poly, 1]];
nfs = RegionNearest /@ MeshPrimitives[poly, 1];
rds = RegionDistance /@ MeshPrimitives[poly, 1];
centroid = Mean[First[poly /. Polygon -> List]];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Thick], poly, Orange, 
   Line[{p, #[p]}] & /@ nfs, Point[centroid]}], {{p, centroid}, 
  Locator}]
```

[image: trilinears]